# Assigning instance variables obtained through reflection in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, instance-variables

I have data in tab-separated values (TSV) text files that I want to read and (eventually) store in database tables.  With the TSV files, each line contains one record, but in one file the record can have 2 fields, in another file 4 fields, etc.  I wrote working code to handle the 2-field records, but I thought this might be a good case for a generic method (or two) rather than writing new methods for each kind of record.  However, I have not been able to code this because of 2 problems:  I can't create a new object for holding the record data, and I don't know how to use reflection to generically fill the instance variables of my objects.

I looked at several other similar posts, including [Datatable to object by using reflection and linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382553/datatable-to-object-by-using-reflection-and-linq/27945914#27945914)

Below is the code that works (this is in Windows, if that matters) and also the code that doesn't work.

```
public class TSVFile
{
    public class TSVRec
    {
        public string item1;
        public string item2;
    }

    private string fileName = "";

    public TSVFile(string _fileName)
    {
        fileName = _fileName;
    }

    public TSVRec GetTSVRec(string Line)
    {
        TSVRec rec = new TSVRec();

        try
        {
            string[] fields = Line.Split(new char[1] { '\t' });

            rec.item1 = fields[0];
            rec.item2 = fields[1];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Bad import data on line: " + 
                Line + "\n" + ex.Message, "Error",
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        return rec;
    }

    public List<TSVRec> ImportTSVRec()
    {
        List<TSVRec> loadedData = new List<TSVRec>();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            string Line = null;
            while ((Line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                loadedData.Add(GetTSVRec(Line));
            }
        }

        return loadedData;
    }

    // *** Attempted generic methods ***
    public T GetRec<T>(string Line)
    {
        T rec = new T();  // compile error!
        Type t = typeof(T);

        FieldInfo[] instanceVars = t.GetFields();

        string[] fields = Line.Split(new char[1] { '\t' });

        for (int i = 0; i < instanceVars.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            rec. ??? = fields[i];   // how do I finish this line???
        }

        return rec;
    }

    public List<T> Import<T>(Type t)
    {
        List<T> loadedData = new List<T>();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            string Line = null;
            while ((Line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                loadedData.Add(GetRec<T>(Line));
            }
        }

        return loadedData;
    }
}
```

I saw the line
    T rec = new T();
in the above-mentioned post, but it doesn't work for me...

I would appreciate any suggestions for how to make this work, if possible.  I want to learn more about using reflection with generics, so I don't only want to understand how, but also why.

Comment: What's the compile error? I'm guessing it says you need to constrain `T`, by adding `where T: class`. Because there's a chance that T could be something which is uninstansiatable, so you get a compile error.

Comment: " but I thought this might be a good case for a generic method (or two) rather than writing new methods for each kind of record." generics of course assume some **common features/behaviour**, which is defined by a generic constraint e.g. something like `where T: MyBaseClass`. Different members on different types don´t match this very wll in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, being a TSV it makes more sense to either use a generic class with a string array of values, or if you have concrete types, and you really want to a generic way to instantiate them (without instead using a factory pattern), you could simply give them a `params string []` constructor and use activator createinstance.

Comment: TSVRec should have a `List<string>` for the values. Add methods to convert them to different types. Essentially, figure out what you'd need if you were writing [`System.Data.DataRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=netframework-4.8), and then just use DataRow and DataTable. There's no problem here that generics are well-suited to solving, other than possibly using `List<T>` for a collection of some field or record type known at compile time. When your generic class or method turns into a pile of reflection, it's not really generic.

Comment: Generics are immensely useful, but they're not the right solution to most problems.

Comment: @NibblyPig, the specific error for the line T rec = new T(); is:
error CS0304: Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint
So I think you were right about that - at least adding "where T: class, new()" as constraints on the method made the compiler error go away.  (Thanks!)  These method constraints are still like strange voodoo to me.  But this is how I can learn it...

Comment: @EdPlunkett, thanks for your suggestion - let me see if I really understand what you're suggesting...  Rather than have different class definitions for different tables, I can simply define TSVRec with 1 member:  public string[] items;  Then it can be used whether the table has 2 fields or 22 fields.  My code can finally go back over the List of TSVRecs and put the values into the database.  Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: Use `List<String>` rather than an array. But yes, that’s the idea. It will simplify everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish @EdPlunkett had posted his suggestion as an answer, rather than a comment, so I could mark it as the answer...

To summarize:  to do what I want to do, there is no need for "Assigning instance variables obtained through reflection in generic method".  In fact, I can have a generic solution without using a generic method:

```
public class GenRec
{
    public List<string> items = new List<string>();
}

public GenRec GetRec(string Line)
{
    GenRec rec = new GenRec();

    try
    {
        string[] fields = Line.Split(new char[1] { '\t' });

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
            rec.items.Add(fields[i]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Bad import data on line: " + Line + "\n" + ex.Message, "Error",
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    return rec;
}

public List<GenRec> Import()
{
    List<GenRec> loadedData = new List<GenRec>();
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
    {
        string Line = null;

        while ((Line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            loadedData.Add(GetRec(Line));
    }

    return loadedData;
}
```

I just tested this, and it works like a charm!

Of course, this isn't helping me to learn how to write generic methods or use reflection, but I'll take it...

Comment: You got it. The one suggestion I'd make here is to initialize `items` in its declaration: `public List<string> items = new List<String>();` When you create a class with `new`, it should be ready to use.